# Is it possible to move Notification Center icon to the left from the Clock

Tags: windows-10

In a recent update Microsoft swapped Notification Center and Clock icon positions so that Notification Center is the last icon in the taskbar. Is it possible to swap them back?

Comment: Have you tried dragging it to a new position?

Comment: Yes but doesn't work. I can drag only regular tray icons.

Comment: Other than turning the notification center icon off, i'm not sure

Answer (score 9):

This change was such an outrage that I've written a little app to put it back how it was. Executables + source available [here](https://github.com/opusman/ClockPositionRighteousifier).

Simply drop a shortcut to the executable into your startup folder to run it automatically. If you launch the .exe a second time it will quit itself and undo the change it made. No warranties, etc.

Comment: maybe upload source to github?

Comment: @Poma good idea, I have updated the link

Comment: Is there any possibility to move it left a little bit more, to the left of the language icon (like it was pre-update)? Or give some tips on what needs to be edited in the code?