# Move Windows 10 clock back where it belongs

Tags: windows-10, clock, action-center

The Anniversary Update put the Action Center to the rightmost place that previously belonged to the clock. I want to swap them back. How can I do that?

(I know that I can disable the Action Center icon, but I want to retain it as the second rightmost icon.)

Is there a registry tweak or a mod like Classic Shell that can give me this simple UI tweak?

Comment: There is not a registry modification that can be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [article](http://winaero.com/blog/move-clock-to-the-end-of-the-taskbar-in-windows-10/) details how to use a third party program to swap the clock and action center.

For lazy people:

This is the [program](https://github.com/opusman/ClockPositionRighteousifier) you need.

And the instruction from the website:

> 1. Point your browser to the author's GitHub (the link above). There, you'll find the app's source code along with the compiled binaries.
> 2. Download everything by clicking "Clone or Download -> Download ZIP". Then unpack the binaries to any folder.
> 3. If you are running a 32-bit Windows 10 version, go to the folder CPR_x86. Otherwise, go to the folder CPR_x64. Right click the file
>      ClockPositionRighteousifier.exe and open its properties. Tick
>      "Unblock" in the properties window. Repeat this step for cprdll.dll.
> 4. Once this is done, you can start ClockPositionRighteousifier.exe. The date/time and Action Center icons will be swapped, with the clock
>      moving to the end of the taskbar.

If you need any more detail, please visit the article i linked. They have screenshots and everything.

EDIT: Here is an [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1110188/is-it-possible-to-move-notification-center-icon-to-the-left-from-the-clock) from the program's author.

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing). 
You should block quote text that has been written by some else. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help).
I've fixed it for you this time, but please pay attention to this in future.